# Calculate $ \mathbb{E}\{G v v^H G^H\} $ if $v$ is a unit norm vector and $G$ is a matrix with i.i.d. $\mathcal{CN}(0,1)$ elements

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-variable, expected-value, linear-algebra

Let $v\in \mathbb C^n$ be an $n \times 1$ complex unit norm vector (i.e. $\sum|v_i|^2=1$). Also, let $G$ be an $m \times n$ matrix with i.i.d. $\mathcal{CN}(0,1)$ elements, meaning that each element $G_{ij}$ follows a [standard complex normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_normal_distribution#Circularly-symmetric_and_zero_mean_complex_normal_distribution) i.e. is a complex number with real and imaginary parts independently distributed as $\mathcal N(0,1/2)$.

What is the expectation $ \mathbb{E}\{G v v^H G^H\} $, where $v^H$ denotes the conjugate transpose of $v$? Note that this is a $m\times m$ matrix, and I need to compute the expected value of this matrix-valued random variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $w = Gv$. Its elements are $w_j = \sum G_{ij}v_i$ and the expected value you want to compute is $\mathbb E[ww^*]$. So let's write it down:

\begin{align}
\mathbb E[w_j w^*_k] &= \mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n G_{ij}v_i \sum_{l=1}^n G_{lk}^*v^*_l\right]=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{l=1}^nv_iv_l^*\mathbb E[G_{ij}G_{lk}^*]\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{l=1}^nv_iv_l^*\delta_{il}\delta_{jk} = \delta_{jk}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n|v_i|^2 = \delta_{jk},
\end{align} which is zero when $j\ne k$ and one when $j=k$, i.e. $\mathbb E[ww^*]=\mathbf I$.

Comment: Assume that the mean is $\mu$ ($\ne 0$) and the variance $=v$. Could you plz tell me if it is possible to calculate the expectation  in this case? thank you!

Comment: Mean of what and variance and of what?

Comment: of the elements of $G$. $\mu$ and $v$ instead of $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Well, if the elements are independent then $\mathbb E[G_{ij}G_{lk}^*] = \mathbb E[G_{ij}]\mathbb E[G_{lk}^*]=\mu^2$ for two different elements and $\mu^2+v$ for the same element.  So it seems that the expected matrix will have $\mu^2+v$ on the diagonal and $\mu^2$ elsewhere.

Comment: Let's take $n=2$. Then, $\sum_{i=1}^2 \sum_{l=1}^2 v_iv^*_l \mathbb{E}[G_{ij}G^*_{lk}]$. For $j \ne k$ we have: $v_1(v_1^*+v_2^*) \mu^2 + v_2 (v_1^*+v_2^*)\mu^2 = (1+v_1v_2^*+v_2v_1^*)\mu^2 \ne \mu^2$ or I am wrong ?

Comment: Oh right, in my previous comment I assumed that $v$ is a random unit vector, but it is actually supposed to be fixed. Then you will have to live with these $v_iv_l$ terms I am afraid.

Comment: What we get and why if we suppose that $v$ is a random unit vector ? Thank you so much!